# How to determine coordinate of grid elements of an image

Tags: python, image, algorithm, matplotlib

Given an image of with a known dimension (eg. 14782 x5495 pixels) and a desired square size (e.g. width,height = 696 pixels) size, how can I get the coordinates of each element in the grid?

[image]

In actuality, my image has no grid. But I'd like to get the coordinate as if the grid exist as shown above.

The coordinate is define as follows:

> The x and y are the coordinates (in pixels) of the upper left corner
>   of the selection. The origin (0,0) of the coordinate system is the
>   upper left corner of the image.

The core majority of the grid element size is fixed for all given input image. (e.g. square with size width x height = 1000x1000 pixels). The shape of the surrounding elements of the grid is not squared, that's ok.

So exactly like the grid scheme as shown in the image above.

The actual image is [downloadable here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16295340/04_709_channel-3.tif.zip) (160MB).

Comment: RowNum  = Y / GridCellHeight = Y / 696 ?

Comment: @MBo: how about X? Can you give example code?

Comment: Sorry, but you don't see analogy? ColNum = X / GridCellWidth = X / 696

Comment: Do you want to calculate the grid from answers as given below, or do you for some reason actually want to process the image and measure locations of grid points from there?

Comment: @VBB, at the end of the day I want to crop the grid into individual images based on the coordinate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like this is what you want:

```
x = [i for i in range(696, 14782, 696) for j in range(696, 5495, 696)]
y = [j for i in range(696, 14782, 696) for j in range(696, 5495, 696)]
```

to test it

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
img = imread('04_709_channel-3.tif')
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For image with width `w`, height `h` and pixel buffer array `data`, the pixel coordinates at index `i` are given by `x = i % w, y = i / w`, where `%` is modulus and `/` is integer division.

EDIT: by the index `i`, I mean increasing first by `y`, and then by `x`, i.e. the *inverse* operation is `i = y * w + x`

Comment: How can we define `i` based on interval, i.e. square size ?

Comment: By convention `i` starts from zero in the top-left corner, increases by `x` coordinate, and then by `y` coordinate